# Iterate over key/value and display it

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to render a key - value on the view(ScrollView) but not getting success on the code below:

```
render(){
  const MyResult = this.state.data.map((myData) => {
    Object.keys(myData).map((key) => {
      console.log(key + " - " + myData[key]);    
      return( 
        <View>
          <Text>{key} - {myData[key]}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    });
  })


  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <ScrollView>
       {MyResult}
     </ScrollView>
   </View>
  )}
}
```

My console.log is displaying everything ok and i guess the error starts on the Object.keys... The display on the simulator obviously is not showing anything.

How can I iterate over keys,values and display it?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the outer `.map(...)` callback, i.e. `MyResult` is an array that contains only `undefined` as values. I think what you actually want/need is *flatMap*.

Comment: I've never used flatMap. What's the best way of doing it?

Comment: A custom implementation is 3-5 lines of code, or use a preexisting implementation such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.flatmap . Of course you can also just flatten `MyResult` (assuming you are returning a result from the outer `.map` callback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix mentioned in the comments, you're not "returning" anything from the outer map. Just try adding a `return` before `Object.keys` and see if it works, like such:

```
 const MyResult = this.state.data.map((myData) => {
   return Object.keys(myData).map((key) => {
      console.log(key + " - " + myData[key]);    
      return( 
        <View>
          <Text>{key} - {myData[key]}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, i got the idea now. I'm gonna study stg about flatMap also.